# What are the eigenvalues of T?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the eigenvalues of the linear operator

$T \begin{bmatrix}
    a    &   b  \\
    c    &   d  \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    2b    &   ia+c  \\
    -3d    &   i(a-b)  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

on the space of two by two complex matrices? I cannot find any by hand or by checking with Mathematica. There may not be any, but I am skeptical of this because then the question I am trying to answer becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear operator on a finite-dimensional complex vector space must have an eigenvalue, by e.g. the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

If we use the basis
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
for the vector space of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices, the map $T$ has matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
i & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3 \\
i & -i & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix} $$
We then find that the characteristic polynomial of this matrix (and hence of T) is
$$ t^4 - 2i t^2 -3i t + 6i $$
This has four rather nasty complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write the transformation as a 4 by 4 matrix and then compute the eigenvalues. Wolframalpha gives 4 distinct complex eigenvalues:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+of+%5B%5B0%2C2%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5Bi%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C3%5D%2C%5Bi%2C-i%2C0%2C0%5D%5D